# Why is there a nested IO monad, IO (IO ()), as the return value of my function?

Tags: haskell

Why does this function have the type: 
`deleteAllMp4sExcluding :: [Char] -> IO (IO ())`
 instead of `deleteAllMp4sExcluding :: [Char] -> IO ()`

Also, how could I rewrite this so that it would have a simpler definition?

Here is the function definition:

```
import System.FilePath.Glob
import qualified Data.String.Utils as S

deleteAllMp4sExcluding videoFileName =
  let dirGlob = globDir [compile "*"] "."
      f = filter (\s -> S.endswith ".mp4" s && (/=) videoFileName s) . head . fst 
      lst = f <$> dirGlob
  in mapM_ removeFile <$> lst
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`<$>` when applied to `IO`s has type `(a -> b) -> IO a -> IO b`. So since `mapM_ removeFile` has type `[FilePath] -> IO ()`, `b` in this case is `IO ()`, so the result type becomes `IO (IO ())`.

To avoid nesting like this, you should not use `<$>` when the function you're trying to apply produces an `IO` value. Rather you should use `>>=` or, if you don't want to change the order of the operands, `=<<`.

Comment: my intuitive feeling it it helps : `removeFile` adds 1 effect. if we want just 1 effect in the end, we have to feed if something with 0 effect. `lst` has an effect already. so we need to remove it first, by using the bind which (stage a computation that) runs the effect to get the value with 0 effect

Answer (score 8):

Riffing on sepp2k's answer, this is an excellent example to show the difference between `Functor` and `Monad`.

The standard Haskell definition of `Monad` goes something like this (simplified):

```
class Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

However, this is not the only way the class could have been defined.  An alternative runs like this:

```
class Functor m => Monad m where
    return :: a -> m a
    join   :: m (m a) -> m a
```

Given that, you can define `>>=` in terms of `fmap` and `join`:

```
(>>=)  :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
ma >>= f = join (f <$> ma)
```

We'll look at this in a simplified sketch of the problem you're running into.  What you're doing can be schematized like this:

```
ma       :: IO a
f        :: a -> IO b
f <$> ma :: IO (IO b)
```

Now you're stuck because you need an `IO b`, and the `Functor` class has no operation that will get you there from `IO (IO b)`.  The only way to get where you want is to dip into `Monad`, and the `join` operation is precisely what solves it:

```
join (f <$> ma) :: IO b
```

But by the `join`/`<$>` definition of `>>=`, this is the same as:

```
ma >>= f :: IO a
```

Note that the `Control.Monad` library comes with a version of `join` (written in terms of `return` and `(>>=)`); you could put that in your function to get the result you want.  But the better thing to do is to recognize that what you're trying to do is fundamentally monadic, and thus that `<$>` is not the right tool for the job.  You're feeding the result of one action to another; that intrinsically requires you to use `Monad`.